# In a windows 8 app, when clicking on a group, how to show a page that has clickable tiles

Tags: microsoft-metro

I have a windows 8 grid app, however, when I click on a group, I don't want the GroupDetailPage. Instead, I need a page that has multiple tiles which are clickable links.
Something similar to the app store, when you click a particular group, say Games, you get all the games, arranged in a grid and it is a clickable link.

Any help is very much appreciated.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the existing GroupDetailPage removing the content about the group, and leaving just the list of items. Or you could modify the destination of the group heading click to a completely new page that you generate.

Are you using C#/XAML, HTML5/JS?

If you are looking to mimic tile animations and display the MetroJS library is pretty cool: 
http://www.drewgreenwell.com/projects/metrojs